# Using CMake to compile in OpenCV-2.4.3

Tags: opencv, cmake

Hi I have written a basic program to open an image file. I am trying to use CMake to compile it. Thsi is what my CMake file looks like:

```
         cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
         project( textures )
         find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
         add_executable( textures textures.cpp )
         target_link_libraries( textures ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

When I run "cmake .", I got the following error.

```
         CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package):
         By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
         asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
         CMake did not find one.

         Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
         of the following names:

         OpenCVConfig.cmake
         opencv-config.cmake

         Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
         "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
         provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
         installed.


         -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Any thoughts on what this means and how I can solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CMake is looking for the file FindOpenCV.cmake, so make sure you have that file (you can search online for someone else's implementation). Then put this file in the proper directory and add this command after the project line in your CMakeLists.txt file"

```
 set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/relative/path/to/your/file/")
```

where CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR is where your source code sits.